deploy keycloak on the docker swarm cluster: ERROR: Failed to execute the 'build' command. ERROR: No value present
I'd like to migrate keycloak, but I've got an error in the service logs that doesn't really speak for itself.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: registry.ccms-capgemini.fr/keycloak/keycloak:20.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    # entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --auto-build
    command:
    - start
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: ${KCLNAME}
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: ${DBPORT}
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
      KC_DB: ${DBV}
      KC_DB_NAME: ${DBNAME}
      KC_DB_URL: ${DBHOST}
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${DBUSER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: ${KCLKLOG}
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KC_HTTPS_CLIENT_AUTH: request
      KC_HTTPS_PROTOCOLS: TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2
      KC_FEATURES:
          authorization
          token-exchange
          docker
          impersonation
          scripts
          upload-scripts
          web-authn
          client-policies
          dynamic-scopes
    volumes:
      - ./configs/keycloak/conf:/opt/keycloak/conf
      - ./configs/keycloak/keystore:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.keystore
      - ./configs/keycloak/datas:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    ports:
      - "8098:8080"

and my .env file:
DBV=POSTGRES

DBNAME=keycloak

DBUSER=keycloak

DBPASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

KCLNAME=load_balancer_url

DBHOST=RDS_db_url

DBPORT=5432

PAF=true

KCLKLOG=INFO

JTO=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled

I've tried several commands and I've expanded the environment variables to the max

Make this change and try in you compose file
  Replace KC_DB: ${DBV}  with  KC_DB: postgres

